FastAPI: Loading a Model through Pickle and Making a Prediction. What is the best way to do it?
I am building an API where I need to load a model through pickle and make a prediction
The code is below:
from fastapi import FastAPI
import uvicorn
import joblib
from utilities import *  # upload the functions
from schema import Customer  # load the schema
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
import os
import numpy as np
import asyncio

app = FastAPI()

path = 'data/'

X_test = import_test_data(path + 'X_test.xlsx')

MODEL_FILE = "./model/model.pkl"  # path to the model   
   
async def predict_client(data:Customer):

    model = joblib.load(MODEL_FILE) # loading model parameters
    y_hat_test = model.predict(X_test)

    # get the predicted probabilities
    y_hat_test_proba = model.predict_proba(X_test)[:][: , 1]

    default = y_hat_test_proba[0] >= 0.5    

    return {"probability_of_defaulting": float(y_hat_test_proba[0]), "is_defaulting": bool(default)}        

if __name__ == "__main__":     
    uvicorn.run("main:app", host="0.0.0.0", port=8000, reload=True)

The code above works fine as it is. When I load the model through async def predict_client(data:Customer): The API works and I get an output with a prediction. However, my problem is that the variable model is a local one as it is described inside the function.
When i start loading the model (without using async def predict_client) I get as error as shown below:
model = joblib.load(MODEL_FILE)           
print(model['model'].coef_) 

I get an error as follows:
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "xxxxx-packages\joblib\numpy_pickle.py", line 658, in load     
    obj = _unpickle(fobj, filename, mmap_mode)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "xxxxx/venv\Lib\site-packages\joblib\numpy_pickle.py", line 577, in _unpickle
    obj = unpickler.load()
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\pickle.py", line 1213, in load
    dispatch[key[0]](self)
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\pickle.py", line 1538, in load_stack_global
    self.append(self.find_class(module, name))
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\pickle.py", line 1582, in find_class
    return _getattribute(sys.modules[module], name)[0]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\pickle.py", line 331, in _getattribute
    raise AttributeError("Can't get attribute {!r} on {!r}"
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'WoE_Binning' on <module '__main__' (built-in)>

It seems that the script does not have time to load the model and it runs into an error when it tried to read print(model['model'].coef_).
I tried to fix that issue by doing the following changes.
async def read_model(MODEL_FILE):

    model = joblib.load(MODEL_FILE)

    return model

model=asyncio.run(read_model(MODEL_FILE))
print(model['model'].coef_)

but again i get similar error:
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'WoE_Binning' on <module '__main__' (built-in)>

How can I successfully load the model once? When I do it through a function the model is a local variable that I cannot re-use.
Thank you

did you use some variable WoE_Binning when you created pickle? It may need to load module with WoE_Binning to unpickle it.

@furas thanks for your reply. Yes WoE_Binning is being read here from utilities import *  # upload the functions . It is being read fine in the first case but in the second case I get an error as explained above

maybe show FULL error message - starting at word Traceback. And show code where you load it outside function - maybe code has to be in different place outside code - e.g, inside if __name__ == "__main__":. Or maybe you should import it from utilities import WoE_Binning without *. Eventually in function use global model to make it global.

The API worked with the following code without returning any error
import pickle    
from fastapi import FastAPI,  HTTPException
import uvicorn
import joblib
from utilities import *
from schema import Customer
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
import os
import numpy as np
import asyncio

## Upload data ###
path = 'data/'

MODEL_FILE = "./model/model.pkl"

X_test = import_test_data(path + 'X_test.xlsx')

app = FastAPI(
    title="Credit Risk Scoring",
    description="A simple API to predict if the customer will default or not.",
    version="0.1.0",
)   


## Predict 


def read_model(MODEL_FILE, X_test):

    model = joblib.load(MODEL_FILE)     
    
    X_test=X_test.head(1)
    y_hat_test = model.predict(X_test)
    y_hat_test_proba = model.predict_proba(X_test)[:][: , 1]

    # if not y_hat_test:
    #     raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Model not found.")

    default = y_hat_test_proba[0] >= 0.5

    return {"probability_of_defaulting": float(y_hat_test_proba[0]) , "is_defaulting": bool(default)}

    # return model


@app.post('/client/predict') 

def predict_client(data:Customer):        

    return read_model(MODEL_FILE, X_test) 
    
if __name__ == "__main__":     
    uvicorn.run("main:app", host="0.0.0.0", port=8000, reload=True)

